# Turbo-rails not functioning in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hotwire-rails, turbo-rails

My app:

- ruby 3.1.2
- rails 7.0.4
- importmap-rails 1.1.5
- turbo-rails 1.4.0

In development, everything behaves as expected, but in production (Ubuntu 22.04) NOTHING turbo-related seems to work:

- Links always trigger a complete page reload
- turbo-confirm dialogs are not shown
- turbo streams do not connect
- etc.

I realize that this question is vague but I would greatly appreciate pointers, where should I look, what steps I might take to diagnose the problem.

Thanks!

## UPDATE

Thanks to newcomer Ivan, it occurred to me that I had failed to take the obvious step to check the browser's console for errors.

I found and fixed a bug (obviously different from Ivan's) in a small Stimulus.js controller and now Turbo is again doing its thing.

I do apologize for wasting people's time but hope that this exchange may serve some purpose, a reminder to do your homework before asking for help.

Cheers

Comment: could you share a link to the deployed application? hard to say whats wrong based on your description.

Comment: @Bergrebell, your comment (together with Ivan's answer) has indeed contributed to the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Met the same issue, and solved it! in my case it was not turbo`s fault, but just another problem.
What you should do:
Go on your site in production, then to browser console, there should be errors, which must be fixed to site works. in my case it was [(picture of my browser console) file not found 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WYiW.png), due wrong path to file in index.js. **I solved my problem by** changing

```
import SortableController from './sortable_controller'
```

to

```
import SortableController from 'controllers/sortable_controller'
```

i fount solution to it here: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/issues/55