# Turbo Rails not working in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, turbolinks

I have successfully deployed my first Rails app on production mode to a Digital Ocean Droplet.
I have developed the app in my local computer with some Turbo Frames working correctly, but in production environment, the Turbo Rails is not working at all.

I have read this thread [Turbo-rails not functioning in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75688791/turbo-rails-not-functioning-in-production) but this is not my case, as I don't see errors in my browser console.

I am using ruby 3.1.3, rails 7.0.6.
Links work as HTML regular links.

I have tried doing:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails turbo:install
```

I have also tried doing:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails turbo:install:redis
```

And reload nginx server but it is not working.

In the `production.log` file there are no errors, just shows that when I click a link that should work as a turbo frame, it behaves as a HTML regular link.

This is the first time I ask a question here, so forgive me if there is lack of details.

**EDIT**

By not working I mean that links that I have inside turbo_frame_tags does not lead to only updating the content inside the turbo frame but instead refreshes the whole page.
I am absolutely not sure that all my javascript components are initializing properly. As I am new to the language I have verified everything I could, running assets:precompile does not throw an error if it helps

These are the portions of the code that are not working:

edit.html.erb:

```
<div class="top-padding">
  <%= turbo_frame_tag "new_item" %>
  <%= link_to "Agregar ítem", new_invoice_invoice_item_path(@invoice), data: { turbo_frame: "new_item" }, class: "btn btn-info" %>
</div>
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= turbo_frame_tag "new_item" do %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```

When I click on the link_to showed in the edit.html.erb file in development, it renders the code in the new.html.erb file inside the "new_item" turbo_frame_tag on the edit.html.erb page.

In development environment, the console log shows this:

```
Started GET "/invoices/249/invoice_items/new" for ::1 at 2023-09-20 08:30:12 -0300
        Processing by InvoiceItemsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"invoice_id"=>"249"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/application_controller.rb:7:in `set_current_user'
  Invoice Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 249], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/invoice_items_controller.rb:4:in `new'
  **Rendering layout C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/turbo-rails-1.4.0/app/views/layouts/turbo_rails/frame.html.erb
  Rendering invoice_items/new.html.erb within layouts/turbo_rails/frame**
  ProductCategory Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "product_categories".* FROM "product_categories" ORDER BY nombre ASC
  ↳ app/views/invoice_items/_form.html.erb:5
  Rendered invoice_items/_form.html.erb (Duration: 292.5ms | Allocations: 4561)
  Rendered invoice_items/new.html.erb within layouts/turbo_rails/frame (Duration: 297.3ms | Allocations: 4954)
  Rendered layout C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/turbo-rails-1.4.0/app/views/layouts/turbo_rails/frame.html.erb (Duration: 317.0ms | Allocations: 5249)
Completed 200 OK in 351ms (Views: 328.0ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms | Allocations: 7711)
```

In production environment, the console log shows this:

```
I, [2023-09-20T11:32:48.395055 #301414]  INFO -- : [e395a581-dda5-4c86-81f5-d45192437773] Started GET "/invoices/58/invoice_items/new" for 190.97.11.201 at 2023-09-20 11:32:48 +0000
I, [2023-09-20T11:32:48.398207 #301414]  INFO -- : [e395a581-dda5-4c86-81f5-d45192437773] Processing by InvoiceItemsController#new as HTML
I, [2023-09-20T11:32:48.398298 #301414]  INFO -- : [e395a581-dda5-4c86-81f5-d45192437773]   Parameters: {"invoice_id"=>"58"}
I, [2023-09-20T11:32:48.465989 #301414]  INFO -- : [e395a581-dda5-4c86-81f5-d45192437773]   Rendered invoice_items/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 61.6ms | Allocations: 116>
I, [2023-09-20T11:32:48.468273 #301414]  INFO -- : [e395a581-dda5-4c86-81f5-d45192437773]   Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 64.0ms | Allocations: 12766)
I, [2023-09-20T11:32:48.468709 #301414]  INFO -- : [e395a581-dda5-4c86-81f5-d45192437773] Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 59.2ms | ActiveRecord: 7.7ms | Allocations: 13874)
```

**UPDATE:**
Following Axel recommendations:

- I ran `RAILS_ENV=production rails turbo:install`
- I do have `import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"` in app/javascript/applications.js
- I do have `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` in my layouts/application.html.erb file
- I have the line `pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true` in my config/importmap.rb file
- I don't have a app/assets/javascripts folder. Maybe there is some issue?
- I opened the Netowrk tab and I do have a turbo.min-something.js file that it being loaded
- I tried to check if my local code is the same as my production server code and I haven't found any differences

Comment: The question is mostly fine, but you'll need to explain "not working" in more technical terms. Are you sure the `Rails` JavaScript components are loading and initializing properly inside your application when loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By not working I mean that links that I have inside turbo_frame_tags does not lead to only updating the contento inside the turbo frame but instead refreshes the whole page. I am absolutely not sure that all my javascript components are initializing properly. As I am new to the language I have verified everything I could, running assets:precompile does not throw an error if it helps

Comment: Edit your question to add the details -- comments are not permanent.

Comment: My trick is to add `console.log("Yo")` to `application.js` to be sure that stuff is hooked in properly. If you don't see that, you need to check that your asset pipeline is running properly. Newer Rails installations depend on things like `bin/dev` being operational at the time in addition to Puma.

Comment: Alex, you are right, Turbo is not running, how could I check for javascript issues?

Comment: "RAILS_ENV=production rails turbo:install" - did you run that on your production server? just make sure that your local code is the same as your production server code. are you using importmap-rails or jsbundling-rails? I assume importmaps, since that's the default. you should have "import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"` in `app/javascript/applications.js` which should be loaded in your layout with `javascript_importmap_tag`. actual `turbo.js` file is pinned in `config/importmap.rb` and comes from `turbo-rails` gem. if you think you've messed something up, create a new rails app and compare configs.

Comment: also make sure you don't have `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` as that could override the other *application.js* file. also just open "Network" tab and see what files are being loaded, one of which should be turbo.min-something.js (unless you're using jsbundling)

Comment: well it's a pickle, I pretty much listed everything that could be obviously wrong. so this is something not obvious. could you make a new test app and run it in production mode locally and see if it behaves the same (set logging to debug in production). I don't use windows for development or production, so there could be something I'm just not aware of in that environment.